# Angular Cookie Resets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I am creating car searching module using Angular + REST Api.

I have read most of the articles here none of them had problem which i have come across;

Angular Cookies works fine on localhost, when i uploaded it to server it's not working as it should .

> on lading page i have few fields which user selects and these information stored inside cookie
>   as it hits search button navigates to Search page and tries to get information from cookies but fails to get information which user has stored , i am getting default values .

I have created small service code snippet.

```
.service('Filter',['$cookieStore','Search',function($cookieStore,Search){
    return {
        get: function(){
                        return (angular.isDefined($cookieStore.get('filterParams')))?$cookieStore.get('filterParams'):Search;
                    },
        set: function(value){
                        $cookieStore.put('filterParams',value);
                    },
        clear: function(){
                $cookieStore.remove('filterParams');
            }
        }
}])
```

Comment: I have very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782802/angulars-cookies-only-work-on-localhost/30783457#30783457. Unfortunately I have not solved this problem yet. Please keep me updated, if you find a solution!

Comment: yup i have resolved that use https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage