# Angular's $cookies only work on 'localhost'

Tags: angularjs, azure, iis, cookies, localhost

Brace yourself, a strange Angular / IIS problem is coming:
I have created an Angular 1.4.0 application that uses $cookies to store the oauth access token after a user logged in.

What works beautifully on localhost fails whenever I deploy the website to an IIS server (I tried Azure and a remote one). I can not understand why. It is always the same procedure but saving / reading the cookies seems to work only locally.

The backend (with the API) runs on Azure and has not been touched. The frontend always connects with this Azure-API but does only work when hostet locally.

Do you have any idea?
My code looks like this:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/account/login",
    method: "POST",
    data: loginData,
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}
}).then(
    function (success) {
        $cookies.put('access_token', success.data.access_token);
        $cookies.put('refresh_token', success.data.refresh_token);

        // 'test' contains the correct token on localhost
        // 'test' is undefined whenever deployed to an iis
        var test = $cookies.get('access_token');

        deferred.resolve(results);
    },
    function (error) {
        deferred.reject({"loginError":-1})
    }
);
```

Could it be that the IIS has a special cookie policy that prevents the cookie access?

**UPDATE 1:**
Please don't get me wrong, I do not want the IIS to manage or track my session state. I just want to be allowed to use cookies for storing my OAUTH access token.

**UPDATE 2:**
Fun fact: At the very first request that is sent to the server after the login procedure, the access token can be read out of the cookies. Every request after thatfails because `$cookies.access_token` is undefined. And I swear (by the old gods and the new) that I do not delete it!

I am thankful for every hint or help!

Comment: Can you please add some http header data?

Comment: If the Api is on another domain you should check if you have cors enabled.

Comment: or you could check the domain in the http request.

Answer (score -1):

Can you log and check what value you are getting from IIS for success.data.access_token

if it is session cookie token then you have to check IIS configuration.

Please refer below link for validating session cookie settings

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754725(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: The `success.data.access_token` contains the OAUTH access token that I want to provide in the header of every future HTTP-Request to my API. I do not want to store the session state in that cookie. Only the access token is needed. But it seems not to get saved whenever I deploy my solution elsewhere than localhost.

Comment: @Raja: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please use comments for your questions.